# Prevent duplicate database requests in a single page load

Tags: node.js, express, couchbase

I've got a website set up using nodejs and express that makes calls into a Couchbase database. I've noticed that some pages are performing logic where the same couchbase documents are requested multiple times in a single page load.

Is there a recommended method to avoid this? I'd like to cache the first result and reuse it any for any additional calls on that page load. I was looking at Redis but I think that might be more of a longer-term cache rather than just for a single page load.

Comment: In the graphql world one would use [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) to batch the database calls, maybe it can work with normal back-end as well.

Comment: Couchbase has a built-in memory-first architecture. So chances are that you are pulling documents from memory in Couchbase. It would be redundant to use Redis (in fact, Couchbase has a new "Ephemeral Bucket" feature, which means the data is stored entirely in RAM).

Comment: I guess I would like to know, are you sure the database access is slowing down your request, and if so, how are you accessing Couchbase?

Comment: It's possibly not! I'm coming from a PHP/mySQL background into a nodejs/Couchbase environment. I'm making assumptions based on past experience without doing any profiling but thats good to know. I wasn't aware of that